# base64 image and html.fromhtml android

Tags: android, base64

My data are stored in html format on db.

The image are stored in base64 format (as a string in db).

I am trying to show this data.

My textView is setted like this:

> setText(Html.fromHtml(content));

all html tags in 'content' are being displayed correctly. Except 'img' tag (which contains a base64 encode image).

So, my question is:
the tag 'img' of 'Html.fromHtml' can decode a string with base64 image?

p.s: The place where the tag is show just a little gray square. No got errors.

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Html.fromHtml` combined with your own implementation of `Html.ImageGetter`.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler%29).

When overriding `Html.ImageGetter.getDrawable`, convert the Base64 string into a byte array (you can use `android.util.Base64`) and feed it into `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` to produce a `Bitmap` which you can then pass into the constructor of a `BitmapDrawable` to return.

For example:

```
Html.fromHtml(content, new Html.ImageGetter() {
        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            byte[] data = Base64.decode(source, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);                
            return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        }
}, null);
```

Comment: I got this error: 'Base64 cannot be resolved.' I am using Android 1.6. And 'getResources' say: The method getResources() is undefined for the type new Html.ImageGetter(){}

Comment: Android 1.6 don't contains android.util.Base64. Now I am using this http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html. But getResources still returning error.

Comment: You need to get this from a `Context`.

Comment: @Munir I got it, before return the bitmapDrawable use this: `bitmapDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());`